# Indexing columns across multiple tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to optimize the following join query:

A notification is a record that says whether a user has read some activity. One notification points to one activity but many users can be notified about an activity. The activity record has some columns such as the workspace the activity is in and the type of activity.

This query gets the user non-comment notifications that have been read in a specific workspace ordered by time.

```
explain analyze
select activity.id from activity, notification
where notification.user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'
and notification.read = true

and notification.activity_id = activity.id

and activity.space_id = '6d702c09-8795-4185-abb3-dc6b3e8907dc'
and activity.type != 'commented'
order by activity.end_time desc
limit 20;
```

The problem is that this query has to run through every notification the user has every gotten.

```
Limit  (cost=4912.35..4912.36 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=138.767..138.779 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=4912.35..4912.36 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=138.766..138.770 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: activity.end_time DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=32.57..4912.34 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=1.354..138.606 rows=447 loops=1)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on notification  (cost=32.01..3847.48 rows=124 width=16) (actual time=1.341..6.639 rows=1218 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'::uuid)
                    Filter: read
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 4101
                    Heap Blocks: exact=4774
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on notification_user_id_idx  (cost=0.00..31.98 rows=988 width=0) (actual time=0.719..0.719 rows=5355 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'::uuid)
              ->  Index Scan using activity_pkey on activity  (cost=0.56..8.59 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.108..0.108 rows=0 loops=1218)
                    Index Cond: (id = notification.activity_id)
                    Filter: ((type <> 'commented'::activity_type) AND (space_id = '6d702c09-8795-4185-abb3-dc6b3e8907dc'::uuid))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning time: 0.428 ms
Execution time: 138.825 ms
```

**Edit:** Here is the performance after the cache has been warmed.

```
Limit  (cost=4912.35..4912.36 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=13.618..13.629 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=4912.35..4912.36 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=13.617..13.621 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: activity.end_time DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=32.57..4912.34 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=1.365..13.447 rows=447 loops=1)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on notification  (cost=32.01..3847.48 rows=124 width=16) (actual time=1.352..6.606 rows=1218 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'::uuid)
                    Filter: read
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 4101
                    Heap Blocks: exact=4774
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on notification_user_id_idx  (cost=0.00..31.98 rows=988 width=0) (actual time=0.729..0.729 rows=5355 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'::uuid)
              ->  Index Scan using activity_pkey on activity  (cost=0.56..8.59 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1218)
                    Index Cond: (id = notification.activity_id)
                    Filter: ((type <> 'commented'::activity_type) AND (space_id = '6d702c09-8795-4185-abb3-dc6b3e8907dc'::uuid))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning time: 0.438 ms
Execution time: 13.673 ms
```

I could create a multi-column index on user_id and read, but that doesn't solve the issue I'm trying to solve.

I could solve this problem myself by manually denormalizing the data, adding the space_id, type, and end_time columns in the notification record, but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

I would expect Postgres to be able create an index across the two tables, but everything I read so far says this isn't possible.

So my question: what is the best way to optimize this query?

---

**Edit:** After creating the suggested indexes:

```
create index tmp_index_1 on activity using btree (
    space_id, 
    id, 
    end_time
) where (
    type != 'commented'
);

create index tmp_index_2 on notification using btree (
    user_id,
    activity_id
) where (
    read = true
);
```

The query performance improved 3x.

```
explain analyse
select activity.id from activity
INNER JOIN notification  ON  notification.user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'
    and notification.read = true
    and notification.activity_id = activity.id
    and activity.space_id = '6d702c09-8795-4185-abb3-dc6b3e8907dc'
    and activity.type != 'commented'
order by activity.end_time desc
limit 20;

Limit  (cost=955.26..955.27 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=4.386..4.397 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=955.26..955.27 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=4.385..4.389 rows=20 loops=1)
        Sort Key: activity.end_time DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..955.25 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.035..4.244 rows=447 loops=1)
              ->  Index Only Scan using tmp_index_2 on notification  (cost=0.56..326.71 rows=124 width=16) (actual time=0.017..1.039 rows=1218 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'::uuid)
                    Heap Fetches: 689
              ->  Index Only Scan using tmp_index_1 on activity  (cost=0.56..5.07 rows=1 width=24) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1218)
                    Index Cond: ((space_id = '6d702c09-8795-4185-abb3-dc6b3e8907dc'::uuid) AND (id = notification.activity_id))
                    Heap Fetches: 1
Planning time: 0.484 ms
Execution time: 4.428 ms
```

The one thing that still bothers me about this query is the `rows=1218` and `loops=1218`. This query is looping through all of the read user notifications and querying against the activities table.

I would expect to be able to create a single index to read all of this in a manner that would mimic denormalizing this data. For example, if I add space_id, type, and end_time to the notification table, I could create the following index and read in fractions of a millisecond.

```
create index tmp_index_3 on notification using btree (
    user_id,
    space_id,
    end_time desc
) where (
    read = true 
    and type != 'commented'
);
```

Is this not currently possible within Postgres without denormalizing?

Comment: 138ms (0.1 seconds) seems quite fast. How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question including the definition of all indexes.

Comment: Indexes apply to single tables. You cannot create an index across multiple tables. If 138 ms is still too slow for you, then you will need to denormalize your data.

Comment: One thing you could do is to extend the index `notification_user_id_idx` with a filter (or create an additional index) using `where read` to index only the notifications that are already read, which would decrease the index size and make the  Bitmap Index Scan faster as it has to look up fewer rows.

Comment: Unrelated (to performance), but: you should stop using those ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause and start using modern, explicit `JOIN` operators

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, check out my latest edit. I'm looking for some pretty extreme performance here. This query gets executed a lot and I've been able to optimize other queries to achieve 0.0x ms performance...

Comment: So that query with 4ms execution time is a bottleneck? How often do you run that? A thousand times a second?

Comment: I simplified the query slightly for the sake of asking the question. But its been called 46.6M times in the last month. About 1000 times per minute. It accounts for about 14% of Postgres CPU.

Answer (score 1):

looking to  your code you should use for filter a composite index  on

```
table notification  columns  : user_id, read, activity_id


table activity columns space_id, type, id
```

and for query and order by you could also add end_time   in composite for activity

```
   table activity columns space_id, type, id, end_time
```

and you should also use explict inner join sintax

```
select activity.id from activity
INNER JOIN notification  ON  notification.user_id = '9a51f675-e1e2-46e5-8bcd-6bc535c7e7cb'
    and notification.read = true
    and notification.activity_id = activity.id
    and activity.space_id = '6d702c09-8795-4185-abb3-dc6b3e8907dc'
    and activity.type != 'commented'
order by activity.end_time desc
limit 20;
```

Comment: last suggestion removed

Comment: Hmm. Can you explain why you've included `activity_id` in the notification index? And why it's last? Also why is `id` in the activity index? Seems odd...

Comment: the activity_id is added  for let the index resolve all the data needed  for the query  ..is lhe last  ..because si not so relevant for    for filter  (where clause)  in this way the index contain all the info and can avoid the access to the table data .. for the type of index  respect the where condition  this  column could be placed in the position you prefere  .. check for selectivit for the right position

Comment: Hey @scaisEdge, check out my latest edit in my post. I've incorporated your indexes.

Comment: Obviosly  ,,if you change the data schema and reduce the relation you improve performance but this is related  to the application ad db design aspect that only you can know .. anyway seems that the my  suggestion  improve the performance  ..

Answer (score 1):

Add the index:

```
create index ix1_activity on activity (space_id, type, end_time, id);

create index ix2_notification on notification (activity_id, user_id, read);
```

These two "covering indexes" could make your query real fast.

Additionally, with a little bit of luck, it will read the `activity` table first (only 20 rows), and perform a Nested Loop Join (NLJ) on `notification`. That is, a very limited index walk.